# excel vba multiple charts in new sheet

Tags: vba, excel, charts, macros

I have an issue with preparing macro which would select 3 ranges in sheet and then create new sheet with 3 charts from this data. How can I prepare one?
Here is what I have at this moment but doesn't work: `ActiveChart.Location Where:="Inwestycje wykresy"` is highlighted and 'Type missmatch' error occurs.
Do I have to also include charts dimensions and position?
Here is my code:

```
Sub InwestycjeWykresy()
Range("B3:N5").Select
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Inwestycje").Range("B3:N5"), PlotBy:=xlRows
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Inwestycje wykresy"
With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Alerty"
End With
Worksheets("Inwestycje").Activate
Range("B6:N7").Select
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Inwestycje").Range("B6:N7"), PlotBy:=xlRows
ActiveChart.Location Where:="Inwestycje wykresy"
With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Eskalacje"
End With
Worksheets("Inwestycje").Activate
Range("B8:N10").Select
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Inwestycje").Range("B8:N10"), PlotBy:=xlRows
ActiveChart.Location Where:="Inwestycje wykresy"
With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Nadzor"
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

On the second and third times as you're trying to add to an existing sheet you need to do `ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Inwestycje wykresy"`

I've not tried it but [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195785(v=office.11).aspx) would imply that would be the correct syntax.

---

On your further comments around positioning you'll need something like:

```
With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Alerty"
    With .Parent
        .Height = 325
        .Width = 500
        .Top = 100
        .Left = 100
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, it solved my error! However, now I have those 3 charts in one new sheet but they are not properly located - first one covers whole sheet and two others are small and cover each other. Probably I need to contain some info about their sizes and position

Comment: [This](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/ResizeAndMoveAChart.html) goes into some detail about the best way to achieve that.

Comment: I added this to every chart                                                                             With ActiveChart.Parent
         
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Alerty"
    .Height = 325 ' resize
         .Width = 500  ' resize
         .Top = 100    ' reposition
         .Left = 100   ' reposition
End With

Comment: You'd have to change the Top and Left in each one or they'd all be in the same place.

Comment: but i had error : 'object doesn't support this property or method' and highlighted .HasTitle = True

Comment: If you take out the `.HasTitle=True` bit does it work? I'd imagine that it would have a title by default anyway.

Comment: I deleted this and now there is .Height = 325 highlighted and same error

Comment: Also, the `.HasTitle` and `ChartTitle.Characters.Text` are under `ActiveChart` not `ActiveChart.Parent` like the other parts.

Comment: See edit for positioning. Some are under Parent, some aren't.

Comment: I used your formula, but still have highlighted .Height = 250 and error that 'object doesn't support this propoerty or method'